# accessing dynamic variables from a form

Tags: php, mysql, variables, dynamic

I used to have `register_globals` turned `ON` (I know - bad bad bad horribly bad) and now I'm changing it up and the specific application is my DVD collection. Adding a DVD presents a set of checkboxes for genres/categories (i.e. drama, comedy, etc). Each genre is coming out of a database table so I can add new genres as needed. The problem here is that it generates its fieldname (checkbox name) from an abbreviation in this **db** table.

IE I'll have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="drama" />Drama
<input type="checkbox" name="bio" />Biography
(etc)
```

So what I was doing before was, with the script that made the entries, it would run through the list of abbreviation names and if it matched the input `($_POST['drama'])`, it would indicate that this DVD falls into that category.

The present problem now is, with global variables turned `off`, how can I dynamically gather those `$_POST values`?  I tried looping through the database and spitting out a concatenated variable trying to declare them in this format:

`$drama=$_POST['drama'];`

This didn't work because I'm mixing up functions with variables and it made a horrible mess.

I hope someone has an answer on how I can read in the `$_POST array` and use it.

Comment: Possible to see your code so far?

Comment: Turn register globals off again. Otherwise others turn you off ;)

Comment: Yes, some of your old code would help a lot... I can't get a clear idea of your goal.

Comment: please re write the question to be more specific and clear. It is, as of now, very vague.

Comment: the posted key of field with name = 'drama' will always be $_POST['drama']. You can foreach the $_POST array to retrieve keys and values separated, but it does not change the things. But still you can instantiate a different variables of $_POST['drama'] without knowing the name, but by getting it with offset from the value's array

Answer (score 2):

Given some checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="drama" />
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="comedy" />
<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="mystery" />
```

you'd end up with `$_POST['genre']` being an array. Asuming drama and mystery are checked off, you'd end up with

```
$_POST['genre'] = array(
    0 => 'drama',
    1 => 'mystery'
);
```

Remember that unchecked checkboxes do not submit with the form, so if you get an entry in `$_POST['genre']`, it was selected in the form.

To check if a category in your DB was selected, you could do something like

```
if (in_array('drama', $_POST['genre'])) {
  ... drama is selected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this example:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    echo "name: $key, value: $value<br />";

}
```